# Silverlight - The program loading circle/percentage not appearing

Tags: silverlight, loading

I have a hobby website:

http://www.chartmygolf.com/Programs/Program.aspx

and for the first time (in six years) someone has said the circle/percentage thing that appears when the program is loading is not appearing, and consequently the program does not load. What could be causing this?

He has installed Silverlight 5.

He is in the USA so I have a bit of time to prepare some ideas. The things I have thought of so far are:

1. A 32/64 bit mismatch between Internet Explorer and Silverlight versions. If it is this how do I check what 32bbit or 64bit versions they have of each?
2. Whether they have Silverlight not Enabled in Internet Explorer. (I think this might be low odds because he tried to load it on firefox and chrome with the exactly the same problem).
3. Does anyone know another Silverlight website page which requires program loading, so I can check if the problem he is having is specific to my page or to Silverlight programs in general?

Jon

EDIT:

Some more info.

1. He is operating on Windows 7.
2. He went to the sample Silverlight page (Silverlight SDK Sample Browser) and it loaded most of the way. What doesn't load is the top section and the sidebar which both have spinning circles around them with 100% in the middle.
3. He is using IE11.
4. In the add-on section the Silverlight is enabled for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

I hope this can be resolved.

Comment: Another silverlight page: [Silverlight SDK Sample Browser](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/). If the XAP actually fails to be loaded, you can double click on the very left end of the status bar in IE which will show a popup with the error message (even if there's no icon indicating the error).

Comment: I've seen antivirus software block xap files from loading.

Comment: The Silverlight SDK Sample Browser does not work for him either. I have edited the post with the new info.